# Converting an unsigned char* to readable string & whats this function doing

Tags: c++, unsigned-char

I have googled alot to learn how to convert my unsigned char* to a printable hex string. So far I am slightly understanding how it all works & the difference between signed & unsigned chars.

**Can you tell me what this function I found does? And help me devlop a function that converts a unsigned char*(which is a hashed string) to a printable string?**

Does the following function do this:
- it iterates over every second character of the char array string
- on each loop it reads the char at the position string[x], converts it to an unsigned number(with a precision of 2 decimal places) then copies that converted char(number?) to the variables uChar.
- finally it stores the unsigned char uChar in hexstring

```
void AppManager :: stringToHex( unsigned char* hexString, char* string, int stringLength ) 
{     
    // Post:

    unsigned char uChar = 0;           

    for ( int x = 0; x<stringLength; x+=2 )     
    {         
        sscanf_s(&string[x], "%02x", &uChar);         
        hexString[x] = uChar;     
    } 

}
```

So I guess that means that it converts the character in string to unsigned(& 2dcp) to ensure that it can be correctly stored the hexstring. Why to 2 decimal places, & wont a simple conversion from signed(if that character is signed) to unsigned result in a completely different string?

**If I have a unsigned char* how can I go about converting it to something that will let me print it out on screen?**

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't decimal places, they're digits. You're saying "don't give me a string shorter than 2; if it's shorter than 2 digits, then pad it with a zero."

This is so that if you have a hex sequence `0x0A` it'll actually print `0A` and not just `A`.

Also, there is no signed/unsigned conversion here. Hex strings are hex strings - they don't have a sign. They're a binary representation of the data, and depending on how they're interpreted may be read as two's complement signed integers, unsigned integers, strings, or anything else.

Comment: Hex "strings" are usually human-readably encoded, actually (otherwise the "hex" part has no meaning at all). And I certainly wouldn't call that "a binary representation of the data", at least in that they're _less so_ than they would be as a basic numerical value. At least less directly so. Hope that made sense.

Comment: Let me better phrase that: "hex strings are an unaltered, more-compact, and more human-friendly view of the underlying binary data"

Comment: so in that function we are just converting from a binary string to a hex string? And not from a char* to a unsigned char*?

Comment: So in effect we are doing this: from ABCD (in decimal 65,66,67,68) to ABCD (in hex 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44) correct?

Comment: Yes and no. You're doing just that, except it doesn't have to be a list of characters in the first place. "unsigned char *" is often used to mean "pointer to anything" or "pointer to some bytes" and so you can actually pass a pointer to an integer and see how C++ stores this integer in binary. You can pass a pointer to whatever you want - this function does not treat the contents that you send in as characters, and will work equally well with anything.